# CSS nest-list - how to subsection

Tags: css

Im creating a list like this one [image]

i want to list rottweiler and doberman like 1.1 and 1.2, but i have no idea how to do it. I copied that css list template and made some modifications.
Here is the code:

```css
#lista2 {
    counter-reset: li; 
    list-style: none; 
    *list-style: decimal; 
    font: 15px 'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

#lista2 ol {
    margin: 0 0 0 2em; 
     counter-reset: section;             
   list-style-type: none;
}

#lista2 li{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
    *padding: .4em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    background: #ddd;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: .3em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;   

}

#lista2 li:hover{
    background: #eee;
}

#lista2 li:hover:before{
    transform: rotate(360deg);  
}

#lista2 li:before{
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: absolute; 
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    background: #87ceeb;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: .3em solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 2em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

#lista2 ol ol li:before{
 counter-increment: li;
  content: counters(li,".") " ";
}
#lista2 ol {
    counter-reset: li;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ol id="lista2">
  <li>Animals
   <ol>
    <li>Dogs</li>
     <ol>
      <li>Rottweiler</li>
      <li>Doberman</li>
     </ol>
    <li>Cats</li>
    <li>Cacatoos</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
 </ol>
```

I hope someone could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plunkr Link - https://plnkr.co/edit/dtn5xgoOOoSmVc4B3LrH?p=preview

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
      <style>
   OL { counter-reset: item }
   LI { display: block }
   LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
  </style>
  </head>

 <body>
 <ol>
  <li>Dogs

  <ol>
   <li>Rottweiler</li>
   <li>Doberman</li>

  </ol>
</li>
  <li>Cats
     </li> 
  <li>Cacatoos</li>
  </ol>

  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
OL { counter-reset: item }
LI { display: block }
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

Comment: thanks, i only had to change a bit my html list to get Dogs in the right spot